# How to retrieve the last row (by time) from each user

Tags: mysql

I have a basic table which hold record of which user viewed which list.
Each time a list is viewed, a record is stored into the "views" table, storing user_ID and list_ID, along with the time at which it is stored.

I want to know for each user when the last viewed a list, and which list it was.

I'm kinda stuck here. It gives me al the latest times, by order, but for some users I get multiple records.

How to sort this out?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39f41/4

Answer (score 0):

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39f41/27/0)

```
SELECT user_ID, list_ID, max(times) as times
FROM views 
GROUP BY user_ID, list_ID;
```

or if you want the view_id returned as well and assuming that larger view_id will always be at a later time than a smaller view_id you can use [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39f41/28/0)

```
SELECT max(view_ID) as view_ID,user_ID, list_ID, max(times) as times
FROM views 
GROUP BY user_ID, list_ID;
```